# initLoader() and onCreateOptionsMenu() possible threading bug/issue

Tags: android

I am fetching some data from SQLite in a Fragment using a CursorLoader. The initLoader() for this is executed in onActivityCreated()...

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>
{
    MenuItem menuItemOne;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
    {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.myMenu, menu);
        menuItemOne = menu.findItem(R.id.menuItemOne);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor)
    {
        menuItemOne.doSomething();
    }
}
```

The above code is simplified for ease of reading. Here is my problem...

- On a **Nexus S**, there is **no problem**.
- On a **Nexus 7**, a **null pointer arises in onLoadFinished**. menuItemOne is null here.

The Nexus S is using Android 4.1.2 and the Nexus 7 is using Android 4.2.2.

- Should I be running initLoader() elsewhere?
- Do you think there is a bug/difference in the Android versions?

Comment: You can try init your Loader in `onCreateOptionsMenu` method, but I'm not 100% sure if it will work. You probably have nullpointer because `onLoadFinished` is executed before `onCreateOptionsMenu`.

Comment: This doesn't work. Already tried :-( It results in a null pointer (but a framework level one) at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1094)

Comment: ... and where is http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setHasOptionsMenu(boolean) call ?

Comment: @Selvin The code is simplified so I removed it, and it wouldn't work at at all on any device if that wasn't called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

they are different devices so there's certainly a difference.

But maybe/probably it's a much more subtle error that you're seeing.
The DB access on the N7 is much faster than on the Nexus S. That way onLoadFinished is called even before your menu is created.

The overral mistake in this code is that it relies on asynchronous and totally independent processes to finish in a defined order.

You can try start loading on different callbacks or do some scheme like the code below to guarantee execution:

```
Cursor c;

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
{
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.myMenu, menu);
    menuItemOne = menu.findItem(R.id.menuItemOne);
    loadFinishMenuInflated();
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor)
{
     c = cursor;
     loadFinishMenuInflated();
}

private void loadFinishMenuInflated(){
    if(c!=null && menuItemOne!=null){
       // do something...
    }
}
```

that way you can guarantee that `// do something` only executes after both items were initialised.

Comment: I have tried running the code on an AndroVM instance. AndroVM is superfast. Far more responsive than a Nexus 7. It works on AndroVM! and it uses Android 4.1.1

Comment: it's not really the speed of the processor or "responsiveness of the UI". A DB access depends on the disk access time more than anything.

Comment: I can see that your solution would work, but IMO it's a bit of a workaround. Surely there is a correct place to initLoader() once all the stuff it might possibly need has been created fully.

Comment: from my answer "You can try start loading on different callbacks ". loader can really be executed at any moment during the life cycle of your activity/fragment. It could be triggered by button click, or list scroll reach the end or any other event. What I mean is that there's no such thing as 'correct place' to do it as it can be done at any moment. Said that the obvious places to give a try would be immediately after the menu inflation or onResume

Comment: I think this is the correct solution. Also onCreateOptionsMenu() unfortunately gets called at different stages depending on Android version. I'm a bit suprised though that I can't find a callback method which is guaranteed to be called after onCreateOptionsMenu. Calling the initLoader() in onCreateOptionsMenu on one device causes  another framework level NullPointerException at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:109‌​4) but is OK on the other.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my other idea:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>
{
    MenuItem menuItemOne;
    boolean executeMenuItemAction = false;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
    {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.myMenu, menu);
        menuItemOne = menu.findItem(R.id.menuItemOne);
        if(executeMenuItemAction )
            menuItemOne.doSomething();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor)
    {
        executeMenuItemAction = true;
        getActivity.invalidateOptionsMenu(); //or getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu() if you are using sherlock
    }
}
```